# Is it a good practice to keep Password field in next step to authenticate the user?

Tags: php, asp.net, laravel, asp.net-mvc-4, laravel-5

I saw Gmail.com and Yahoomail.com login page shows only username and then on form submit shows the new screen where we can enter Password.

Is it good practice to keep the login page in this way? Is it good for security point of view?

Comment: This might be helpful for you. http://security.stackexchange.com/a/85180

Comment: I think it's a matter of UX.

Comment: Some banking websites also have the similar UX where login ID is separated from the password, but those sites include a personalized security image after you entered the login ID for you to validate the site's authenticity.